# How to Display as Html content in Textbox

Tags: asp.net

How to Display Html content in `Textbox` Control

Eg:

```
string text="<b>" + Hi How are you + "</b>";    
txtEditor.Text=text.ToString();
```

I have to display those text in bold Letters, How do i achieve this

Comment: You shouldn't allow html formatting in any of your controls. If you only want to change text appearance, do it with css or style attributes.

Comment: Then, how the third party control providers Create the Html Editors? like tiny Mce Editors

Comment: They perform input validation in some other way. It's a little unclear what are you trying to do. If you just want to format text in a texbox, use attributes. If you want the user to be able to do so, find a wysiwyg editor control and use that instead of textbox.

Comment: I would like to Create my own Html Editor .

Answer (score 1):

You can change the font property of the TextBox:

```
txtEditor.Font = new Font(txtEditor.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
```

Comment: Getting Error:Error 41 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Drawing.Font.Font(System.Drawing.Font, System.Drawing.FontStyle)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: This code is only 'worked in windows application, not in web application as OP use asp.net

Answer (score 0):

See [this link](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/htmleditor/how-do-i-use-the-html-editor-control-cs) for an existing html editor. I **strongly recommend** that you carefully read the paragraph about Cross Site Scripting, whether you decide to use that control or not.

Answer (score 0):

To display text bold in `asp:textbox` control, you can use style at design time or runtime

**in .aspx page Design time**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" style="font-weight:bold;" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

OR

**in Code Behind**

```
textBox1.Font.Bold = true;
```

You can try any one to get desired result. My suggestion over here is that use CSS style to get more advanced formatting in textbox